# volatile pointer without variable

Tags: c, volatile

In C, when I want to put number 5 at address 0x28, I can do it this way:

```
char* x = (char *) 0x28;
*x = 5;
```

If I want, I can do the same without declaring a variable:

```
*((char *) 0x28) = 5;
```

If I want that compiler treats this address as volatile, I can do it this way:

```
volatile char* x = (char *) 0x28;
*x = 5;
```

Can I do it without declaring a variable?

Edit: Let me explain why I want to do "*((char *) 0x28) = 5". I write a blinking LED hello world program for ATmega32U4 and I know that address 0x28 rules the pin to which my LED is connected. And it does work: the C code which you suggested compiles to correct machine code and the LED blinks.

Comment: `(char *) 0x28` is _undefined behavior_ (UB), unless 0x28 was the address of an object.

Comment: @chux, given that volatile is most often use for memory-mapped registers, that would be entirely plausible.

Comment: @zneak, *plausible* is not at all the same thing as *well-defined*.  The C language does not guarantee that it is possible in any way to write a value to an arbitrarily-chosen machine address.  In fact, it goes to some effort to avoid introducing any concept of *machine* addresses into the language at all.  Pointers do not necessarily correspond to those.

Comment: Yes, @IljaEverilä, precisely so.

Comment: @johnbollinger Meant to aim the question at chux, but I guess it ended up pinging you. Anyway I guess it means little in this context if it's implementation defined wrt. undefined behaviour, since no compiler is named and all that. I confess that I don't have a firm grasp on the subject, hence the question originally.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, trying to drop the language lawyer hammer on people doing something so clearly invalid on a standard computer architecture that it has to be non-portable code for an embedded environment wed to its own C compiler isn't doing anyone a service. The C standard is not a ceiling: in fact, that document has a whole section on common extensions.

Comment: @zneak If the user is asking effectively how to do `*((char *) 0x28) = 5;`, then it is also likely the user (or others checking this post) do not realize code "doing something so clearly invalid" applies.  There is no hammer involved, simply a statement that code may be UB.

Comment: I agree, @zneak, that the C standard is not a ceiling, inasmuch as it is possible to target the characteristics of specific implementations.  But the question is not contextualized that way.  And if it were, it would be the unstandardized implementation details that must drive an answer.  And it is important for people to understand that -- both those posing such a question, and those reading it later.  If they already knew all the gory details relevant to them, they would not be asking.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Hammer phrasing: “*X* is undefined behavior (UB).” Coaching phrasing: “The behavior of *X* is not defined by the C standard. Be sure you are using it only in a way supported by your platform, such as accessing a defined hardware register.”

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

```
*((volatile char *) 0x28) = 5;
```

Comment: Good to leave `volatile` in should the address point to a hardware register.